# Chaining return-by-reference calls to access underlying data

Tags: c++, return-by-reference

I worked previously only with pointers and i don't know if references behave the same way in return-statements.
Can I chain multiple return-by-reference methods to access data without fearing for a "dangling" reference which contains garbage? Or would the reference go out of scope before passing it to the function-call above?

See the code below if this is a valid way to pass references (we assume that the indexes are all in range)

```
struct Data {
    //Non-Trivial Data
}

class Container {
    public:
        Data& get(int index) { return m_Collection[index]; }
    private:
        Data[100] m_Collection;
}


class ContainerCollection {
    public:
        Data& get(int containerindex, int dataindex) { return m_Container[containerindex].get(dataindex); }
    private:
        Container[3] m_Container;
}
```

Comment: References behave mostly like automatically-dereferenced pointers. Your code is fine.

Comment: As long as the `ContainerCollection` exists, the `Container`s stored in the `m_Container` exist and as long as the `Container` exists, the `Data` object exists. You do not risk any dangling references here (only UB, should the indices be out of bounds). There's no difference between returning a pointer and a reference in this scenario as the lifetime of the object the return value allows access to is concerned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a valid way of chaining references.

You can chain references within functions without worrying about dangling references (which you should worry with pointers). As long as `m_Container` exists, the reference is available, after that it points to `NULL`.